# Whats the word for this type of person?

Tags: epithet-requests

What do you call a person who takes a stand on an ideology but has no real practical experience or knowledge of it?

Answer (score 3):

The question appears to be too broad. You should necessarily narrow down your request by providing one or two sample sentences. But off the top of my head, the closest thing that I can think of would be the noun [**dilettante**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilettante):

> A person who cultivates an area of interest without real commitment or knowledge.

Example sentence:

> It takes an experienced veteran, not **a political dilettante**, to see policies and processes brought to reality in any meaningful way.
>
> Source: [Tom Homan Is the Right Person at the Right Time to Run ICE](https://cis.org/Cadman/Tom-Homan-Right-Person-Right-Time-Run-ICE)

Answer (score 0):

"Ideologue" can work. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideologue), "an impractical idealist", "an often blindly partisan advocate or adherent of a particular ideology".

"Chauvinist" has [one sense related to this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinist) (this is actually from the definition for "chauvinism"), "excessive or blind patriotism".

Answer (score 0):

a **naif**

> n.
>   1. a naive or inexperienced person. adj.
>   2. naive.

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/naif)

As in:

> In 2012, Popkin had learned about trees to cure this blindness in
>   himself and went from a naif who could barely pick out an oak tree to
>   an amateur arboriculturist who can distinguish hundreds of trees.